# How can in Gulp pass Mocha grep parameter into my task?

Tags: mocha.js, gulp

I have my gulpfile.coffee

```
gulp  = require 'gulp'

coffeelint = require 'gulp-coffeelint'
mocha      = require 'gulp-mocha'
plumber    = require 'gulp-plumber'
gutil      = require 'gulp-util'
watch      = require 'gulp-watch'

handleError = (err) ->
  console.error err.message
  process.exit 1

gulp.task 'test', ->
  gulp.src('test/*-test.*')
    .pipe(mocha(reporter: 'spec'))
    .on 'error', handleError
```

I need run `gulp test --grep group1`, i found [options.grep](https://github.com/sindresorhus/gulp-mocha) but i don't know how proceed parameter from CLI.

Comment: Solved by using `yargs`

Comment: Please write the solved part as an answer and accept it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SOLVED: using yargs npm package

```
gulp  = require 'gulp'

coffeelint = require 'gulp-coffeelint'
mocha      = require 'gulp-mocha'
plumber    = require 'gulp-plumber'
gutil      = require 'gulp-util'
watch      = require 'gulp-watch'
yargs      = require 'yargs'

handleError = (err) ->
  console.error err.message
  process.exit 1

gulp.task 'test', ->
  gulp.src('test/*-test.*')
    .pipe(mocha(reporter: 'spec', grep: yargs.argv.grep))
    .on 'error', handleError
```